# Is it possible to use ActionBarTab without ViewPager in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

It's very easy to use Android Studio to generate a project with a ActionBarTabs inside a ViewPager.But I'm wondering if it's possible to use ActionBarTabs without ViewPager?

Comment: I managed to make it worked.Thanks.

Comment: Here comes another question, is it possible to set different action buttons (menu) for different tab?

Comment: Sorry for post another question here. Anyway, it's also possible and I made it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Design guide for [swiping views](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html#between-tabs) and [Tabs](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html) specifically state that users expect to be able to swipe between tabs. I'd strongly recommend using tabs and allowing swiping between them or picking a different navigation pattern (such as a [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/spinners.html) or a [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)).

Comment: Yes. You're probably right. Actually using ViewPager or not is not not the point. What I want is to set different action buttons for different fragment and asked the wrong question. Anyway I've found the answer by myself.Thanks anyway.